# What is this meaning `Name query nb {random char}<00>`

Tags: networking, tcp, vmware, wireshark, virus

The scene is under `VMWare`, and the os in vm is `Ubuntu 12`.

What I have to say is the network was actually suddenly cut off when I was coding. My two colleagues were all have the problem. It seems very odd. It just is a vm dev environment. Why three person will occur it in a not long time periods. I couldn't ping the IP in VM from my host, and vice versa.

At the first time, I think it is the problem of `network adapter` of VMware. But it didn't work after I removed the network adapter and re-added it.

But this time, I think ping it. But the network is **very slow**. I just ping a IP, not a domain.

So, when I used `wireshark` to see what is the problem.

As the picture show below. I think it is a virus. The **random string** before `<00>`.

[image]

### Anyone can give me the solution or some hints? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's a virus called [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/), from a company called "Google"; Chrome [appears to make various weird name queries](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hl0Knv7p4-4).

Comment: Yes. Thanks very much